# Google Orgchart create marriage

Tags: javascript, treeview, orgchart

Hi im using [`Google Orgchart`](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/orgchart?hl=da#Example) to create a family tree, where I combine three families.

How can I create lines between people who are married but from different families like below.

```
+----------+                  +----------+
| Family 1 |                  | Family 2 |
+----------+                  +----------+
     |                             |
     |                 +-----------+-----------+
     |                 |                       |
+----------+      +----------+           +-----------+    +----------+
|  Husband |------|   Wife   |           | Wife's Bro|----| Bro's GF |
+----------+      +----------+           +-----------+    +----------+
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's impossible with Google Organizational Chart.
Read documentation of data format.

> A table with three string string columns, where each row represents a
> node in the orgchart. Here are the three columns:
>
> Column 0 - The node ID. It should be unique among all nodes, and can
> include any characters, including spaces. This is shown on the node.
> You can specify a formatted value to show on the chart instead, but
> the unformatted value is still used as the ID.
>
> Column 1 - [optional]
> The ID of the parent node. This should be the unformatted value from
> column 0 of another row. Leave unspecified for a root node.
>
> Column 2 - [optional] Tool-tip text to show, when a user hovers over this node.
>
> **Each node can have zero or one parent node, and zero or more child nodes.**

You can build multiple trees but it's impossible to join them. (one of node should have two parents or siblings).

---

Try using other library:

- [lib_gg_orgchart](http://www.fluxus.com.ve/gorka/lib_gg_orgchart/). This library support siblings nodes: [example1](http://www.fluxus.com.ve/gorka/lib_gg_orgchart/lib_gg_orgchart_v04_sample.php?sample=2), [example2](http://www.fluxus.com.ve/gorka/lib_gg_orgchart/lib_gg_orgchart_v04_sample.php?sample=1)
- [Dracula Graph Library](http://www.graphdracula.net/)
- [Protovis](http://mbostock.github.com/protovis/ex/)
- [Ftree](http://code.google.com/p/ftree/)

...or maybe integerate with [Geni](http://www.geni.com/)