# Generating tree with repeatable elements

Tags: php, google-visualization

I want to generate the following tree using google charts:

[image]

The top ones are roots, and the bottom ones are their childs. One child can be included inside many roots.

I want to make organization chart to achieve that.

How can I do that?

Because right now, the child belonging to two roots is not being displayed.

Comment: The organizational chart allow top down one-to-many relations but not many-to-one relations. Unfortunately The organizational chart is just not fit for genealogy. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11528321/google-orgchart-create-marriage

Comment: What should I use instead? Is there some library in google charts?

Comment: From google not that I know of. You can check the ones mentiones in the link I posted